# Can anybody provide a checklist for documents for a conference visa to Netherlands? (from India)

Tags: paperwork, netherlands

I can not find the checklist (specific for India to the Netherlands) anywhere, not even on the VFS website.

Answer (score 3):

The Dutch government provides the following [Visa Advisor](https://consular.mfaservices.nl/schengen-visa/schengen-advisor/) tool to determine what visa you need. AFAIK there  is no special visa category for conferences and you most likely need to apply for general Short-Stay Visa.

The online application form requires a [sign-up](https://consular.mfaservices.nl/create-account) but is then supposed to guide you which documentation is applicable to your situation. It should save your draft application and allow you to resume and complete the application at a later time when you don't have all relevant documents at hand yet.

The generic checklist is [this one](https://www.netherlandsworldwide.nl/countries/india/travel/applying-for-a-short-stay-schengen-visa) :

> - You must submit a passport or other travel document issued within the last 10 years. This must have at least 2 blank pages and be valid
>   for at least another 3 months after the date you intend to leave the
>   Schengen area.
> - You must submit a completed and signed visa application form. Each person travelling with you on your travel document must submit their
>   own visa form. Forms for children under the age of 18 need to be
>   signed by a parent or guardian.
> - If you are under 18 and are travelling without one or both of your parents or guardians, ask them to sign a consent form. Border guards
>   may ask to see this form when you arrive in the Netherlands.
> - In a country where visa applications are processed by an external service provider, in most cases your digital photo will be taken at
>   the Visa Application Centre. In all other cases you yourself will have
>   to submit a photo with your application. This photo must meet Dutch
>   requirements for passport photos.
> - When you submit your application your fingerprints will be taken. These will remain valid for 59 months. Some applicants, such as
>   children under the age of 12, do not need to have their fingerprints
>   taken.
>
>   Did you provide biometric data (fingerprints and photo) within the
>   last 59 months prior to your current application? Then you can choose
>   to have someone else submit your application for you. You do not have
>   to appear in person. This also applies if you had your fingerprints
>   taken within the last 59 months for a visa application submitted
>   through another Schengen member state.
>
> *Please note that if, during the assessment of your application, it appears that your fingerprints are not in the system, you will have to
> come and submit them. Also, you can always be invited for an interview
> if your application gives reason to do so.*

Note that at the moment there are still COVID-19 travel restrictions independent of Visa requirements.  One of which is the  EU entry ban that applies to travellers who live outside the EU/Schengen area. You may require to show proof of vaccination/recovery or maybe negative PCR test taken shortly before boarding.